# EXCEL 2010: Change the range of an auto filter with a MACRO

Tags: vba, excel

The following gave me the Range of the autofilter on worksheet Planning

```
rAddress = Worksheets("Planning").AutoFilter.Range.Address
Range("C12").Select
Range("C12") = rAddress =[$B$4:$I$183]
```

I would like to change the autofilter range without removing the current autofilter by using the following range as input.

```
Worksheets("Planning").Select
Rownumber = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("B:B")) - 1

Range("$B$4:$I$" & (Rownumber + 4))
```

How do I code a macro to change to this new range WITHOUT removing and reinstating the autofilter?

Comment: What do you mean by "change to this new range"? What are you trying to get it to do?

Comment: JoeMalpass: Thanks!
I have written a MACRO to add NEW TASKS at the bottom of a dynamic range on which the auto filter operates. Part of this range is a vlookup that returns an entry from standard projects. There are also a number of Responsible persons. The user wants to select specific Responsible when discussing their actions. Then the user wants to add a NEW TASK to the dynamic range. If the user has not completed the previous addition IN FULL the cursor ends at the bottom of the range BUT the AutoFliter "hides" this position. Risk is NEW TASK will be added with a gap! Need to prevent this

Answer (score 0):

The Autofilter range will expand itself when you add new rows to your Worksheet.  If you need 4 more rows, just add them to the bottom:

```
'Returns $A$1:$C$13 (your value will depend on your data).
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Address
ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1).Value = "foo"
'Is now $A$1:$C$14
Debug.Print ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.Address
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience is, that the AutoFilter needs values in the first column to detect added rows properly. So if you only want the AutoFilter to act on newly added data, simply fill in values into the first column.